# How to configure jest-mongodb(@shelf/jest-mongodb) in typescript-node project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jestjs

I am working on integration testing, So getting a data from database makes testcase execution slower. Tried with jest-mongodb to set up a temp db. but could not find a proper documentation for setting up jest-mongodb in typescript-nodejs project. please help me to overcome this issue.

test.ts(db configuration file based on this test suites connect to db)

```
export default {    
    jwtPrivateKey: 'secretkey',
    // Testing Database configuration
    MongoDB: {
        dbConfig: {
            user: 'user name',
            host: 'some host',
            port: 'some port',
            authMechanism: 'some mechanism',
            authSource: 'access level',
            dbName: 'database name',
            metadata: 'initializer'
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 0):

Create the file: `typings/global.d.ts`:

```
declare namespace NodeJS {
  export interface Global {
    __MONGO_URI__: string;
  }
}
```

Then, in your `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": { ... },
  "include": ["./src/**/*", "./typings/*"]
}
```

Comment: Hey i have updated config file in the question, could you please give some elaborated answer so that i can able to understand clearly.

Answer (score 0):

One way to have this setup is as follows:

Configure Jest with TypeScript via Babel:

```
yarn add --dev babel-jest @babel/core @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-typescript
```

Then in your babel config you would have:

```
// babel.config.js
 module.exports = {
  presets: [
    ["@babel/preset-env", { targets: { node: "current" } }],
    "@babel/preset-typescript"
  ]
};
```

You can find the docs here [Jest TypeScript support via Babel](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started#using-typescript)

And finally add @shelf/jest-mongodb to your jest.config.js

```
// jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  preset: "@shelf/jest-mongodb",
  verbose: true
};
```

Now you're good to go. In your test file, you'll have access to the test db URL, through:

```
process.env.MONGO_URL
```

Or

```
const globalAny: any = global;
globalAny.__MONGO_URI__
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `@shelf/jest-mongodb` has removed the exposed global variables and has replaced them with a single environment variable instead.  Conveniently this works around the need to declare global typings.

From https://github.com/shelfio/jest-mongodb#readme :

```js
const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb');

describe('insert', () => {
  let connection;
  let db;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    connection = await MongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, { // <= MONGO_URL env var set
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true
    });
    db = await connection.db(); // <= env var (presumably) includes the db so no longer need to pass this
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await connection.close();
  });
});
```

There is therefore no need to modify your `tsconfig.json` config to support this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `process.env.MONGO_URL` instead.

```
import { connect } from 'mongoose'

beforeAll(async () => {
  await connect(process.env.MONGO_URL as string)
})
```

Answer (score -3):

Jest MongoDB provides all required configuration to run your tests using MongoDB.
[Described Here](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mongodb)

First you need to install @shelf/jest-mongodb,

```
yarn add @shelf/jest-mongodb --dev
```

then Specify preset in your Jest configuration:

```
{
  "preset": "@shelf/jest-mongodb"
}
```

Then start Writing your tests. like :

```
const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb');

describe('insert', () => {
  let connection;
  let db;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    connection = await MongoClient.connect(global.__MONGO_URI__, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
    });
    db = await connection.db(global.__MONGO_DB_NAME__);
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await connection.close();
    await db.close();
  });

  it('should insert a doc into collection', async () => {
    const users = db.collection('users');

    const mockUser = {_id: 'some-user-id', name: 'John'};
    await users.insertOne(mockUser);

    const insertedUser = await users.findOne({_id: 'some-user-id'});
    expect(insertedUser).toEqual(mockUser);
  });
});
```

There's no need to load any dependencies. See Jest-MongoBD [Documentation](https://github.com/shelfio/jest-mongodb) on GitHub.

[DO VOTE TO THIS ANSWER, IF ITS HELPFUL TO YOU]

Comment: Hey I have referred documentation and implemented in javascript code. It works fine and test cases are passing. but when trying with typescript __MONGO_DB_NAME__  throws an error. please read the question clearly and answer. If you give some sample code instead of copy paste documentation it would be really helpful.

Comment: The question is about typescript and the `global.__MONGO*` variables that are injected by `@shelf/jest-mongodb`, and not about just how to use the module.